# curl_multi_exec performance conern

Tags: php, loops, curl, parallel-processing, sleep

The following example is taken from:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-close.php#example-3540

> This example will create two cURL handles, add them to a multi handle,
>   and then run them in parallel.

```
<?php
// create both cURL resources
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

$running=null;
//execute the handles
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh,$running);
} while ($running > 0);

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);

?>
```

I adjusted it a bit to achieve my needs. I want to call only one resource but execute local code while it is requested. This works just fine and my performance concern is also valid for the example without modification.

I produced resources that take 5 seconds to deliver and used them as $ch1 and $ch2

As expected the total execution took only 5 seconds instead of 10.

But in the do loop I added a small counter that revealed that curl_multi_exec and respectively the do loop get executed ~5000000 times on my local machine during the ~5 seconds. That would be about one run per microsecond, which is really quite a lot.

I am worried that this occupies extensive CPU resources while just waiting for the requests to finish and basically doing nothing.

I remembered that one of the first things I learned at a Java course was to avoid endless loops and work with Thread sleeps/interrupts instead for the reasons stated above.

However we don't have threads here and I don't know whether this is valid for PHP too.

As this is an official example I thought I rather ask the experts here first.

I thought about implementing a short sleep in the do loop. Somehing like `usleep(100)`.

- Is my concern valid?

  - If so, is the sleep solution a good one?

    - If so, what would be a good sleep interval? I would love something as small as possible so no process gets slowed down, but I also don't want to hammer the server.
  - If not, why?

Comment: I can't say personally, but you could test with adding the micro sleeps. If it increases the time, then the permanent calls to `curl_multi_exec` are necessary. 100 microseconds look good to me anyway, maybe more to make the test result more visible.

Comment: If you do decide to use usleep(100) be careful if you are running on windows Windows.  See warnings [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php#allnotes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program loops like crazy like this because curl_exec_multi() will always execute and try to do something and your program doesn't wait accordingly for something to act on before you call it again.

See [curl_multi_select](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php) for the PHP function that is explicitly made for this purpose and should solve your problem.